# HTML and JavaScript - tic-tac-toe-game, Display score?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i have some problem on displaying the score from the JS game(tic-tac-toe) inside an html tabel. I am not sure on how to do it?

Here is the HTML code: https://bpaste.net/show/9251b57e60fe

HTML:

```
<div id="game_box">


    <h2 align="center"> Welcome to Tic tac toe - 4 pro!</h2>

    <div id="message" align="center"> Messages will go here!</div>
    <table border="0" align="center" class="board" cellspacing="6">
        <tr>
            <td id="s1" class="Square" onclick="nextMove(this);"> </td>
            <td id="s2" class="Square" onclick="nextMove(this);"> </td>
            <td id="s3" class="Square" onclick="nextMove(this);"> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="s4" class="Square" onclick="nextMove(this);"> </td>
            <td id="s5" class="Square" onclick="nextMove(this);"> </td>
            <td id="s6" class="Square" onclick="nextMove(this);"> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="s7" class="Square" onclick="nextMove(this);"> </td>
            <td id="s8" class="Square" onclick="nextMove(this);"> </td>
            <td id="s9" class="Square" onclick="nextMove(this);"> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>


    <!-- Statistik tabel -->
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>X won</td>
        <td>X lose</td>
        <td>Draw</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="score">0</td>
        <td id="score">0</td>
         <td id="score">0</td>
      </tr>
    </table>




        <button id="button" type="button" onclick="alert('Restarting game')"><a href="javascript:startGame();">Start Over</a></button>
```

and here is the JS code:https://bpaste.net/show/ddbfc27a2890

JS:

```
function startGame(){

            for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i = i + 1){ //För clearbox Funktion längst ner
            clearBox(i);

            }
            document.turn = "X";
            if (Math.random()< 0.5){ // För att Slumpa vem som får börja spela.
            document.turn = "O";
            }
            // För att förhindra flytt efter spelet är slut.
            document.winner = null;

            setMessage(document.turn + " gets to start.");
        }




        // Messages Funktion
        function setMessage(msg){
            document.getElementById("message").innerText = msg;
        }



        //  Next Move funktion
        function nextMove(square){
            // För att förhindra att spelet forstätter efter någon vunnit.
            if (document.winner != null){
                setMessage(document.winner + "  already won the game.");

            } else if (square.innerText == ""){ // För att förhindra att man flyttar till samma ruta.
            square.innerText = document.turn;

            // För att den ska switcha turn
            switchTurn();
        } else {
            setMessage("That square is already taken!"); // Förhindra samma ruta.
        }

    }


        // För att switca turn - så att det blir varanan tur.
        function switchTurn(){

            if (checkForWinner(document.turn)){
                setMessage("Congratulations, " + document.turn + "! You win!");
                document.winner = document.turn;
                recordWin(document.winner);

            } else if (checkDraw()){
                    setMessage("Draw"); 

            }else if (document.turn == "X"){
                document.turn ="O";
                // För att texten ovanför spelet varierar - beroende på vems tur det är.
                setMessage("it's " + document.turn + "'s turn!");

            } else if (document.turn = "X") {

                // För att texten ovanför spelet varierar - beroende på vems tur det är.
                setMessage("it's " + document.turn + "'s turn!");   
            }   
        }


        // Hitta vinnare, på alla möjliga sätt, diagonal, lodrätt osv.
        function checkForWinner (move) {
        var result = false;
        if (checkRow(1, 2, 3, move) || 
            checkRow(4, 5, 6, move) || 
            checkRow(7, 8, 9, move) ||
            checkRow(1, 4, 7, move) ||
            checkRow(2, 5, 8, move) ||
            checkRow(3, 6, 9, move) ||
            checkRow(1, 5, 9, move) ||
            checkRow(3, 5, 7, move)){

            result = true;

            }
            return result;
        }


        // Funktion för att hitta vinnaren.
        function checkRow(a, b, c, move){
            var result = false;
            if (getBox(a) == move && getBox(b) == move && getBox(c) == move){
            result = true;
            }
            return result;
        }

        // typ för att kolla om det är X eller O i rutorna
        function getBox(number){
            return document.getElementById("s" + number).innerText;

        }


        // Funktion för att "clear" tomma rutorna.
        function clearBox(number){
            document.getElementById("s" + number).innerText = "";


        }

        // Funktion för att kolla efter DRAW stats.
        function checkDraw(){
            for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i = i + 1) 
                if(getBox(i)=="")
                    return false;
            return true;
        }



        // För att recorda win
        function recordWin(winner){
            if (winner == "X"){
                xWon++;
            }else if (winner == "O"){
                xLose++;
            }else if (winner ==""){
                drawGame++;
            }


            // save();
        }

        function save(recordWin){
        document.getElementById("score").innerText = xWon;
```

}

```
        // Funktion för att spara stats i ?
        function saveStats(){

            totalGames = xWon + xLose + drawGame;
        }
```

Everything else sems to work in the game, but i cant figure out on how to call the score to the HTML tabel.

Thx in advance!

Comment: Just in case the links die, you'll be better adding the code to your question.

Comment: Oh ok i will do that!

Comment: hmm having some problem with posting it...:S

Comment: done it for you bud.

Comment: Thx, hmm i have now added a function;
Function save(recordWin){ 
document.getElementById("score").innerText = xWon; }

and in Html:  <td id="score">0</td>     
So now it generats nr of Win in my tabel, but now i am trying to also add xLose and drawGame, but i am having trouble with it